# How to get client's computer MAC Address and IP in asp.net?

Tags: c#

I want to get client computer MAC address and IP at the time of login for purpose of uniquely identify the client computer.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get the MAC address at all, or the local IP address if the computer is behind a NAT; the best you'll do is the IP of the router behind which the client computer sits (unless the ISP has provided the user with a static, public IP and things are configured properly to expose the client computer directly to the internet).  The link shared by @DanHunex helps when your C# code is running on the client (as in a desktop app) but not to retrieve such information *from* the client when your code is running on a web server.

Comment: Is there any other way to uniquely identify client's computer if my code is running on a web server?

Comment: Sure.  You can add a cookie to your response containing some text like an ID or GUID or whatever, and assuming the client is accepting cookies, it'll send you that value on future requests.

Comment: I used cookie containing GUID but after 24 hours the value is changed itself.

Comment: Cookie expiration dates are configurable.  You just need to figure out how to specify a later expiration date or say "never".  I don't know ASP.NET, but it should be pretty easy; it is in Java.

Comment: I should note that cookies aren't perfect; the user is free to delete cookies on the browser side, so even cookies set never to expire can go away.

Comment: ok, I will try to solve out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get client IP address from request objects [`UserHostAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like

```
Page.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Looks like there is no straight forward way of getting client MAC address except using `WMI` which other answers already have pointed on.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user's IP address you can use Request.UserHostAddress or Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].

Getting the MAC address I am not sure it is so simple. It is not something that is available to the server (ASP.NET) like the IP address is. From what I know you will need to use client scripting and ActiveX or Java applets to get to that information (after multiple installation and security prompts on the users' machines).

So in other words, get IP address by Request.UserHostAddress. Avoid using MAC address and look for another solution if IP is not unique enough for your needs. Maybe combine it with browser User Agent string instead (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] or Request.UserAgent but the latter might not be available in older versions of .NET).

Answer (score -1):

refer to the below link , may be they will be useful for you...
http://forums.asp.net/t/1911211.aspx?Get+Client+Mac+Address+in+Asp+Net+Web+Application

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/187064/i-need-MAC-Address-of-client-machine-using-asp-net#answer1

Comment: These links are for getting the server's MAC.